# What does it mean when there is an unnamed object with function inside?

Tags: javascript

Reading some javascript files and couldn't understand this piece of code. Basically it is an object with a function in it. How do I understand it?

```
{       // Static methods
    function getCurrent() {
        return obj[k].instance
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives SyntaxError. Add more context. BTW `{}` at the beginning of the line means code-block, not object

Comment: I think you need to provide more context, such as what `obj` is and the object that it's part of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an object. It is [**block statement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) which is used for grouping statements. In this case it most likely groups static methods.

Comment: Thank you. I saw some other place grouping statements as well after post the question. So it actually doesn't do anything. Perhaps it was a back end programmer that wrote the code.